# Randomize Function to create a length range in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I was wondering how I would create a randomized string that has a set length range, that range being 8 to 24 characters, instead of it it being a fixed length such as 10.

Comment: What particular problem are you having with that task?

Answer (score 1):

```
Program RandomString;

// Get a random character from A to Z
function GetRandomCharacter: char;
begin
  // Use A random value from 0 to 25 and add that to A
  Result := 'A';
  Inc(Result, Random(26));
end;

// Get a random string of characters from A to Z 
// with a length from 8 to 24 characters
function GetRandomString: string;
var 
  Length: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Get a random length to use from 8 to 24
  Length:= 8 + Random(17);

  // Create a string of random characters with the desired length
  Result := '';
  for I:= 1 to Length do
  begin
    Result := Result + GetRandomCharacter;
  end;
end;

begin
  // Execute Randomize only once in the application
  Randomize;

  Writeln(GetRandomString);
end.
```